# How date and time is handled inside WAR/ZIP?

Tags: java, timezone, zip, file-format, last-modified

The very same file inside the very same WAR file is displayed by `jar tvf myfile.war` as modified at different times at Linux ad Windows.

Linux:

```
ubuntu@alex2:~/trydeploy2$ jar tvf mywar.war | grep custom.css
 23932 Thu Jan 05 02:03:04 UTC 2012 _diffs_classic/css/.sass-cache/custom.css
  7580 Thu Jan 05 02:03:04 UTC 2012 _diffs_classic/css/custom.css
 25817 Tue May 28 00:18:40 UTC 2013 css/.sass-cache/custom.css
  7693 Tue May 28 00:18:40 UTC 2013 css/custom.css
```

Windows:

```
D:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\jar.exe" tvf mywar.war | grep custom.css
 23932 Thu Jan 05 02:03:04 MSK 2012 _diffs_classic/css/.sass-cache/custom.css
  7580 Thu Jan 05 02:03:04 MSK 2012 _diffs_classic/css/custom.css
 25817 Tue May 28 00:18:40 MSD 2013 css/.sass-cache/custom.css
  7693 Tue May 28 00:18:40 MSD 2013 css/custom.css
```

Last file is of interest.

As you see the time component values are coincide but timezones differ.

Machines are really at different timezones.

How to handle this situation? What information is stored inside ZIP and where a mistake can be? Finally I need Linux machine to know modification times correctly.

Comment: I am not sure, but I suspect this problem comes about because of an unfortunate mistake in the specification of the ZIP file format: a failure to specify that times must be in UTC. I guess that file format was designed a very long time ago and it's too late to fix the design problem.

Comment: Yes, probably this is the reason but I would like to know precisely